# Homebrew and qemu security

Tags: macos, homebrew

I want to install qemu on a Mac OS computer. I need to install this software with homebrew.

You will think I am paranoid but I do not trust third party software, including homebrew, qemu and all the dependencies.

Is there a way for me to install and run qemu on a single basic user account, or does qemu need a root privilege ?

Comment: Homebrew doesn't need root privileges to get installed (or to installl additional software).

Comment: I have tried to download and compile qemu sources. But i need to install some depenencies (i do not trust any dependancy and i do not trust homebrew) So how  can i do ? Thanks

Comment: Without the dependencies you can‘t compile qemu. Regarding trust, what is the difference between the qemu sources and those of the dependencies?

Comment: The dependencies are installed on the system whereas qemu is only in my home directory

Comment: If you compile the dependencies yourself, you can easily install them in your home directory as well. But basically it doesn't matter either way, the libraries qemu depends on don't have a life on their own. Unless an application uses them they pose no additional risk.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in some circumstances, you do actually need root privileges in order to run ´qemu`.

Most `qemu` users on macOS are using the `-accel hvf` option. If you compile `qemu` yourself, you will need to codesign it and have the right entitlement on it - otherwise it will require root privileges to manage virtual network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to give it root privileges to do anything, unless you are trying to save files in a directory not owned by your account.

If you are concerned about giving brew root privileges, you can [build qemu from source](https://www.qemu.org/download/#source).

Comment: https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Mac might be the better reference, listing all the required 3rd party libraries as well.